# CSS Replace Font Awesome Icon with image - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to replace a Font-Awesome 'shield' icon with a photo from my media library. I have gotten this far:

.fa-shield:before{content:url("http://www.myimage.png")}

My image displays giant and to the right. I am inexperienced, but when I look at the source code and hover I can see an info line similar to:

i. fa fa-shield before 1572 x 62

I am assuming it is showing my image at 1572 wide. How can I change this and centre my image, before and after photos attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5AoA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9VpE.png)

Comment: Please a relevant code snippet. And show what you mean with "i. fa fa-shield before 1572 x 62"

Comment: You should add your code for better understanding of the problem.